# Can I use Stormland Mirror on my last turn?

Tags: thunderstone-quest

After enough Guardian Keys have been found, and the Guardian revealed, each player gets one more turn per the rules on page 14.

Can a player use Stormland Mirror during that last turn to get another turn, including another potentially very lucrative shot at the Guardian?

[image: Stormland Mirror - magic item - after this turn ends, take an extra turn and destroy this card.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Co-designer Bryan Reese says **yes**:

> "Stormland mirror does give you an extra turn, even on the final turn."

**Source:** Bryan Reese (https://boardgamegeek.com/article/28348033#28348033)

[image: BGG quote screenshot]